# best way to merge two pandas dataframe having 150 k records in each..Merging should happen on one common column like ID

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

best way to merge two pandas dataframe having 150 k records in each..Merging should happen on one common column like ID

df1(1st Datafrma150k records)
df2(2nd dataframe 150k records)
df3 = pd.merge(df1,df2,on='ID',how='left')

is this correct way to merge ?

Comment: Try Dask for large dataset. Please read this doc link https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/enhancingperf.html. Closing this question since it needs more focus.

Comment: Did you try what you wrote? What happened?

Comment: yes.. i got memory issue..may be beacuse i tried to join two same datafame as i dont have the scond dataset ready yet..

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: well.. I have an idea. 
first step: You use `set` to find the common id in df1 and df2
second step: you concat the two dataframes with those ID rows by columns.
the first step already takes care of the joining work, and I know set can do this really quick. The second step just displays the columns you want to see.
if you can share your data that will be helpful ...

Comment: 150k rows isn't really a very big data set. Definitely not worth dask unless you have tons of columns. You've said you tried joining the dataframe to itself? I can't think what would actually happen but that can't be helping. If you don't have your second df ready don't rush to find the next step yet because you'll most likely up with a solution that doesn't answer your issue